# Function to increase count of a tuple in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tuples

So I have a function that takes a character and a list of tuples [tuple is a pair containing a character and an integer]. If the character matches the tuple character, the corresponding number is incremented by one. If not, then the tuple is printed as is.

So basically

```
foo 'a' [('a',1),('b',2),('c',1)]
```

Should yield

```
[('a',2),('b',2),('c',1)]
```

I have written the following code, but understandably, it skips printing over the last tuple:

```
foo a ((x,y):xs) | xs == [] = []
                 | x==a = (x,y+1):foo a xs
                 | x/=a = (x,y):foo a xs

foo 'a' [('a',1),('b',2),('c',1)]
O/P : [('a',2),('b',2)]
```

How do I modify the function such that it considers the last tuple too? I'd also like to be able to add a tuple with a count of 1 if the element is not present in the list of tuples

Comment: `foo a = map $ \(x,y) -> (x, y + if x==a then 1 else 0)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note what happens if we try to apply foo to the empty list:

```
λ> foo 'a' []
*** Exception: <interactive>:(90,1)-(92,40): Non-exhaustive patterns in function foo
```

It is generally frowned upon to use guards for things you can pattern match. Let's rewrite foo a bit, hopefully, it will make the cause of the exception clear and help you see what should be do to fix the problem:

```
foo _ (_:[]) = [] -- the pattern could also be `[_]`
foo a ((x,y):xs) | x==a = (x,y+1):foo a xs
                 | x/=a = (x,y):foo a xs
```

Now it's evident one element lists are discarded:

```
λ> foo 'a' [('a',1)]
[]
```

Let's this. Also, the guard forces us to replicate work, let's remove it.

```
foo _ [] = []
foo a ((x,y):xs) = (x, if x == a then y+1 else y):foo a xs
```

And voilà:

```
λ> foo 'a' []
[]
λ> foo 'a' [('a',1)]
[('a',2)]
λ> foo 'b' [('a',1),('b',2),('c',3)]
[('a',1),('b',3),('c',3)]
```

Comment: Yes it works! Is there also a way to add an element into the list if the element does not already exist, and then set it's count to 1?

Comment: Sure there are ways to that. Why don't you give it a try and if needed ask another question?

Answer (score 1):

Your `xs == []` case needs to be done at the same level as the pattern match, not after it.

```
foo :: a -> [(a, Int)] -> [(a, Int)]
foo _ [] = []
foo a ((x, y):xs)
  | x==a      = (x, y + 1) : foo a xs
  | otherwise = (x, y    ) : foo a xs
```

Your version only checks that the tail (excluding the first element) is empty. You want to check if the *whole* list is empty and handle that case differently.

Side note: If you compile Haskell with `-Wall`, it will warn you about the partial function. I recommend *always* using `-Wall`. 99% of the things it warns you about are genuinely good advice, and the handful of silly warnings can be easily disabled on-demand.

Comment: Yes it works! Is there also a way to add an element into the list if the element does not already exist, and then set it's count to 1?